# Non-interactive docker login in Github Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am trying to run this command inside a Github Actions step running on a Windows agent:

```
echo ${ACR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD} | docker login -u ${ACR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL} --password-stdin spetestregistry.azurecr.io
```

But it returns this error:

```
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

Then I tried this command:

```
echo ${ACR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD} | winpty docker login -u ${ACR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL} --password-stdin spetestregistry.azurecr.io
```

Which produced this error:

```
stdin is not a tty
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out that I was using the Github secrets variable incorrectly. This works:

```
echo ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD }} | docker login --username ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }} --password-stdin spetestregistry.azurecr.io
```